# Python tkinter align buttons with labels problems

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to align the second label(the blue text) under those two buttons(I aligned them on left side), I tried to use frames... or with grid but I still don't know how to do it.. 
Here is the image [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI2om.png) and here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tema 1")
root.geometry("550x600")

first_frame = Frame(root)
first_frame.pack(side=TOP)

first_label = Label(first_frame, text = "Exercitiul 1",font = "Times 15 bold")

button_ex1_1 = Button(first_frame, text = "Enunt", font = "Times 12 italic", command = lambda: btn_ex1_1(l1),height = 1, width = 20)
button_ex1_2 = Button(first_frame, text = "Rezolvare", font = "Times 12 italic", command = lambda: btn_ex1_2(l1),height = 1, width = 20)

l1 = Label(first_frame, font="Times 13 bold", fg="blue" , wraplength = 550, width=55)

first_label.pack(side=TOP)
button_ex1_1.pack(side=LEFT)
button_ex1_2.pack(side=LEFT)
l1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to pack the blue label before packing the buttons.

```
first_label.pack(side=TOP)
l1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
button_ex1_1.pack(side=LEFT)
button_ex1_2.pack(side=LEFT)
```

The packer works by aligning widgets to a side of existing empty space. When you put a widget on the left, the remaining empty space will be to the right of that widget. So, put the things on top first, followed by the things on the bottom, and then the things that go in the middle.

Comment: Thanks but now the buttons are not on center :( are on left side

Comment: @AlinCosmin: the buttons are on the left because that's where you're putting them.